# Regex filtering and excluding forbidden words

Tags: regex, adonis.js

Trying to fulfill these requirements:

- Alphanumeric allowed `[a-zA-z0-9]` or `\w+`
- Only numbers NOT allowed
- At least 8 characters `\S{8,}`
- Forbidden words: Test, pimba, vraw  `^(!?.*Test|pimba|vraw).*$` or `\b(?:(?!word)\w)+\b`

The problem is I can't mix it all together.
Documentation read: [Mozila - Character Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes), [Group and Ranges](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges,),
[indicative Regex](https://indicative-v5.adonisjs.com/docs/regex),

I'm using https://regex101.com/ to try the regex validation.

Tries:

- `\b(?:(?!word)\w)+\b(\S{8,})`
- `^(?=\S*\w+)(\S{8,})\b$`
- `^(?!.pimba|vraw|\d{8}).$`
- `^(?=\S*\w+)(\S{8,})+(!?.*Test)$`

Comment: Please show your attempts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
^(?!\d+$)(?!.*(?:Test|pimba|vraw))\w{8,}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cTxtgH/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!\d+$)`: Negative lookahead to fail the match if we have all digits
- `(?!.*(?:Test|pimba|vraw))`: Negative lookahead to fail the match if any of those substrings appear anywhere in input
- `\w{8,}`: Match 8 or more word characters
- `$`: End

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I place one of the forbidden words in the middle of a string like `123456aaavraw` it passes, but it should not.

Comment: ok I was trying to block complete words. Please try updated regex.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey, @anubhava. Any easy way to allow ALL special characters at once, blocking only spaces (which is already done).

Comment: You mean you want to allow some non-space special characters not covered with `\w`?

Comment: I forgot to mention. I need to allow all special characters but spaces. I did `[\w.!@#$%&*()\\-]` but I had to write every special character. Is there a way to block spaces but allow all others at once? (e.g: `!@#$%&*()-_=<>;.`) So I wouldn't have problem with automatically pass generation.

Comment: ok try: `^(?!\d+$)(?!.*(?:Test|pimba|vraw))\S{8,}$`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you once again.